# ORACLE_SID vs ORACLE_UNQNAME: is there a clear and definitive definition?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have checked documentation, forums and a lot of discussions regarding the subject, but some points are still not clear to me.

From the info I could gather, many people just treat both of them as the same thing ("`ORACLE_UNQNAME` is the database unique name"; "`ORACLE_SID` is the name set to your database"), what sounds very suspicious, since it would be very unnecessarily redudant having 2 variables for the exact same thing.

I suspect that the two follow something like a "taxonomy" schema, being `ORACLE_UNQNAME` the "genus" and `ORACLE_SID` the "species" level.

Thus, there could be more than 1 `SID` defined under a single `UNQNAME`.

Is my conclusion right? Any feedback is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Oracle Database on your laptop, this will most likely apply:

```
ORACLE_SID = DB_NAME = DB_UNIQUE_NAME = SERVICE_NAME
```

My XE laptop installation (docker)

```
sys@XEPDB1> show parameter db_name

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_name                              string      XE
sys@XEPDB1> show parameter db_unique

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_unique_name                       string      XE

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
service_names                        string      XE
sys@XEPDB1> show parameter sid
sys@XEPDB1> -- hey no value for SID found!
```

But as soon as installing an Oracle Database for the Enterprise, things change. An Enterprise installation will require high availability and disaster recovery.
In such an environment this will most likely apply:

```
ORACLE_SID <> DB_NAME <> DB_UNIQUE_NAME <> SERVICE_NAME
```

- ORACLE_SID defines the instance (process + memory).
- DB_NAME defines the name of the database no matter where it is located. Cannot be changed after creation.
- DB_UNIQUE_NAME must be unique in a DR configuration. Defines disk file-layout
- SERVICE_NAME defines the name of the database service. My one HA/DR Oracle Database can serve content for all our schemas (databases) in the one Oracle Database. i.e WEBSHOP1,WEBSHOP2,...,WEBSHOPN ...

If more isolation is needed enter multitenant architecture and pluggable database.

Comment: "An Enterprise installation will require high availability and disaster recovery"  Not true.  What is true is "An Enterprise installation  _may involve_ high availability and disaster recovery"

Comment: Thank you for your time, @Bjarte Brandt, but  things are still unclear to me. I would like to get a little deeper in the concepts of ORACLE_SID (process + memory) and DB_UNIQUE_NAME (Defines disk file-layout). I still cound't get how this concepts turn to pratic when I create and start a db instance.